# can I calculate difference between 6 AM to 12 AM in hours using carbon in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-8, php-carbon

I'm having a problem with the Laravel project and I want to estimate the difference of 2-time in my project using the carbon package. The below code is what I used to calculate.

```
        $carbon_startDate = Carbon::parse($working_time['start_time'])->format('H:i:s');
        $carbon_edate = Carbon::parse($working_time['end_time'])->format('H:i:s');
        $totalDuration = Carbon::parse($carbon_startDate)->diffInHours($carbon_edate);
```

But here I am facing a new problem. I set the start time to 6 AM and the end time is 12 AM. Actually, I want the result to be 18 hours, but I got the result in 6 hours. Anyone can help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 6 hours is correct... 12AM (18 hours later) would be _the next day_...

Comment: You will need to add dates to calculate time differences correctly. Of course in the same day 6am comes after 12am which will result in 6hour difference (which is also correct). But if you were to say 2021-11-18 6am and 2021-11-19 12am you will get the 18hour difference you should be getting.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply, but I'll get time from the database. So I only get the start time and end time. So how do I convert this to a date-time format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a better solution to this problem. So I do it my own way.

here is the code,

```
if($carbon_startDate > $carbon_edate){
    $date= Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    $start_time = Carbon::parse($working_time['start_time'])->format(' H:i:s');
    $first_time = $date.$start_time;

    $date2= Carbon::now();
    $next_date = $date2->addDays(1)->format('Y-m-d');
    $end_time = Carbon::parse($working_time['end_time'])->format(' H:i:s');
    $last_time = $next_date.$end_time;
    $totalDuration = Carbon::parse($first_time)->diffInHours($last_time);
 }else{
    $totalDuration = Carbon::parse($carbon_startDate)->diffInHours($carbon_edate);
    $totalDuration= round($totalDuration/$min_duration);
   }
```